# How Do I Command CSV to Delete thr Rows On Starting from This Row and To That Row

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm having trouble implementing a function.

First here's the snippet:

```
    # LOAD ROWS
    for row in eans:
        gtin_row = row[0]
        if(gtin_row[0].isdigit()):
            print('True')
            gtin = row[0].split(";")
            gtin = gtin[0]
            # DIGIT IS FOUND IN row[0] so START at the next row
            next(eans,None)

           # IF ITEM IS FOUND on Found_list
            if gtin in found_list:
                # STARTING FROM row[0] I mentioned earlier until it finds another row that starts with a digit, delete every row

                if(row[0].isdigit):
                    break
                else:

                    print('Non Digit = Iterate')
                    output = open(csv_file, 'wb')
                    writer = csv.writer(output)
                    writer.writerow(row)                    
                    output.close()
                    next(eans,None)
                    continue
```

I was loading a list, from a `csv` I've commented on how the code was supposed to work, somehow `next()` wasn't working. I'm having trouble starting on `next(eans,None)` because it doesn't point  `row` eans to the next row.

Let's say I have rows like this:

> 3423423
>
> jalsjfslv
>
> fbdbdf
>
> bdfndf
>
> 32532532

I intended to start at `jalsjfslv` delete it and its following rows until it points to `32532532` where `if(row[0].isdigit):` is supposed to work and stops the loop so it can go with the next `gtin`

My code doesn't work with `.next` and `next(list, None)` any idea on how to solve this problem? Really stuck I think i'm missing something.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to avoid using the next statement entirely. The following code accomplishes the task using far simpler concepts.

```
# LOAD ROWS
import csv

csv_file = "aFile.csv"

# The above file is blank. 
found_list = ["3423423"]

eans = ["3423423", "jalsjfslv", "fbdbdf", "bdfndf", "32532532"]
clear = False

output = open(csv_file, 'w', newline='')
output.close()

for row in eans:
    if(row.isdigit()):
        clear = False
        output = open(csv_file, 'a', newline='')
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        writer.writerow([row])   
        output.close()
        print('True')
        gtin = row.split(";")
        gtin = gtin[0]
        if gtin in found_list:
            clear = True

    elif(clear == True):
        print('Non Digit = Iterate')
```

Note that quite a bit of the code that was posted seemed to be out of context. For example, the constant indexing of the previous value seemed to hinder the accomplishment of the task.  Use this concept to fit your code as you see fit.